# lucene.net 64bit OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, 64-bit, lucene.net

I have a Lucene Index that is 313MB running via an ASP.NET website under 64bit.  When I start the app up and the Index is read in with `IndexReader.Open(directory, true)` in the CreateLuceneIndex() method below I see the IIS Express Worker Process bloat to over 4GB and then bang - OutOfMemoryException!

Can anyone explain why and what I need to do to fix the problem please?  Why is this happening when the actual index size is only 313MB?

NOTE: The Container is a DI Container ([Funq](http://funq.codeplex.com/))

```
private void CreateLuceneIndex(Container container)
{
    var directory = CreateDirectory();
    var indexWriter = CreateIndexWriter(container, directory);
    //indexWriter.DeleteAll();

    //var fieldDictionary = CreateIndexFieldDictionary();

    //PopulateLuceneIndex(indexWriter, fieldDictionary);

    indexWriter.Dispose();

    container.Register(new IndexSearcher(IndexReader.Open(directory, true)));
}

private Directory CreateDirectory()
{
    var useAzureBlob = _appSettings.Get("UseAzureBLOBStorage", false);
    var blobStorageEndpoint = _appSettings.Get("blobStorage", string.Empty);

    var directory = useAzureBlob
        ? (Directory)
            new AzureDirectory(CloudStorageAccount.Parse(blobStorageEndpoint), "Catalogue")
            : new MMapDirectory(new DirectoryInfo(Environment.CurrentDirectory));

    return directory;
}

private IndexWriter CreateIndexWriter(Container container, Directory directory)
{
    container.Register<Analyzer>(new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30));
    var analyser = container.TryResolve<Analyzer>();

    var indexWriter = new IndexWriter(directory, analyser, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED);
    indexWriter.SetRAMBufferSizeMB(10.0);

    return indexWriter;
}
```

Comment: What is `container` ? What does it do? Do you get the same exception without it?

Comment: Its a DI container: Funq - http://funq.codeplex.com/

Comment: And the last question *"Do you get the same exception without it?"*?

Comment: Good question - yes I do, just tested that..

Comment: Hard to phantom, a 64-bit process dies on OOM when the operating system's paging file can't be made large enough to provide the backing storage.  A stack trace is pretty essential, this might be an exception thrown by Lucene itself.

Comment: When I go to view the Stack trace it says that an OutOfMemory Exception occurred and all the usual debugging data in VS has the same message.  Is there a trick to getting the stack trace on an OOM exception; can't find one after a quick google...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I haven't yet worked out why but I found that changing from a `MMapDirectory` to a `FSDirectory` resolved the problem for me.